# GitHub Pages not able to update index.html meta tags with create react app(CRA)

Tags: html, reactjs, metadata, create-react-app, github-pages

GitHub pages wrap my create-react-app's index.html with its own index.html file.

The original index.html file has meta tags, the GitHub's does not.

I am not able to alter metadata of Github's index.html file and it does not use the metadata from the original CRA's index.html.

How to fix this?

[image]

The project has the basic React project file structure:

[image]

Comment: can you plz provide the file structure of your project

Comment: It seems that the pages are binded into an iframe

Comment: @HitechHitesh Indeed. I just haven't found a way for setting meta to that iframe.

Comment: As I checked my GitHub page I haven't found that my page is coming in an iframe.  Does you page have an iframe in it where the react app is binded

Comment: As I checked my GitHub page I haven't found that my page is coming in an iframe.  Does you page have an iframe in it where the react app is binded

Comment: @HitechHitesh no, `index.html` uses default `<div id="root"></div>` in its body and `index.tsx` renders a HashRouter which is put to `document.getElementById('root')`.

Comment: GitHub pages does not alter you code, it'll just serve the static assets. Probably issue with your code or build. Can you share more details on it.

Comment: @vatz88 indeed it doesn't. It simply wraps my whole single-page-application into an iframe thus the browser fails to reach inner html page meta tags. I would gladly share more details on this, but I am not sure what would help. Could you advise on what details would be useful to share? Because the project itself is a simple react project made with CRA (no ejects, no alterations except for additional meta tags)

Comment: How are you building it? github pages will only serve root or `docs` folder. Also, it won't run any build process for you. As I can see your index.html is in the public folder.

Comment: @vatz88 I have deployed using [official CRA docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment#github-pages-https-pagesgithubcom). The file structure in `gh-pages` branch which gets deployed is a bit different than the one shown in the questions. `index.html` file lies in root directory along with `static` directory.

Comment: Is the repo public? I'll just check it myself in that case.

Comment: @vatz88 Sorry, no, it's private. However, I can try providing you with the info you need to investigate this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that create-react-app was removing CNAME file from my build folder what caused unnecessary creation of iframe. Moving CNAME file to `/public` directory fixed the issue.

This is where I have found the answer I was looking for: https://github.com/tschaub/gh-pages/issues/127